# zpool cannot properly import missing pool after system crash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, zfs, zpool

I have a raidz3 zpool on Ubuntu 18.04 with the Ubuntu built-in zfs features, there was a system crash recently, I guess it's caused by an unavailable(failed) disk, and after rebooting, the pool was missing:

```sh
$ sudo zpool status
no pools available
```

Tried to list the pool, but it says: `The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.`

```sh
$ sudo zpool import
   pool: content-pool
     id: 3621552755300412622
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices were being resilvered.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
 config:
.
.
.
```

I've confirmed that all the disks are detected by the system properly, can be located in `/dev/disk/by/-id/` / `/dev/`

Tried to import it using following trying, also tried with `-F`/`-f`/`-m`/`-o readonly=on` parameter:

- `sudo zpool import content-pool`
- `sudo zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ content-pool`

All returned:

```
cannot import content-pool': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Also tried to use `zdb -l` to dump vdev labels from the partitions of alive hard drive, seems the label can be retrieved successfully, the output are almost the same, except the `guid:` part, and there are 36 children(0-35) just like to original working raidz3 pool:

```sh
------------------------------------
LABEL 0
------------------------------------
    version: 5000
    name: 'content-pool'
    state: 0
    txg: 8348544
    pool_guid: 3621552755300412622
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'content-ftp'
    top_guid: 11498459744868090541
    guid: 7798174214455629273
    vdev_children: 2
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'raidz'
        id: 0
        guid: 11498459744868090541
        nparity: 3
        metaslab_array: 166
        metaslab_shift: 40
        ashift: 12
        asize: 216041772810240
        is_log: 0
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 7798174214455629273
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D168PVC8-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 215
            create_txg: 4
        children[1]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 1
            guid: 9655586118508030176
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D363TCL9-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 214
            create_txg: 4
        children[2]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 2
            guid: 1036444324318734332
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D363TDVX-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 213
            create_txg: 4
        children[3]:
            type: 'disk'
```

Is there any chance that I can force the import and try to fix the data? Hopefully raidz3 can restore the damaged data? Thank you all!!!

---

**Update**

Somehow after disable autoimport by setting `zfs_autoimport_disable=0` in `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf`, `zpool` status works

```sh
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: content-pool
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.  There are insufficient replicas for the pool to
    continue functioning.
action: Destroy and re-create the pool from a backup source.  Manually marking the device
    repaired using 'zpool clear' may allow some data to be recovered.
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    content-pool                             UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
      raidz3-0                                    DEGRADED     0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D168PVC8  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D363TCL9  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D363TDVX  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D36JR303  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D36JRJD1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56Z35P  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56Z4JD  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZEX2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX21D36PPEKZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4HV3ZZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4LMMMM  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXC1HB4HMLCD  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXN1H84CCEVF  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557Y3SR  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557YAVR  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557YCC2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PX3KS  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PX3YX  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PXTSC  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11DC4497YV  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX31D2504K74  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX31D65A2C9E  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259T63X  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TE9L  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TJU9  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TVTR  ONLINE       0     0     0
        1078152416620325459                       UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574E35-part1
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574KZ5  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574SXZ  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574V07  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX71D65JEZ2C  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX81D6550UR4  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4HSKRY  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX81D65D9LD6  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX91D65DCE04  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX91D65DCKR5  ONLINE       0     0     0
      ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZTEP    FAULTED      0     0     0  external device fault
```

Now the problem has become that how to recover from a faulted pool, I can't do almost any operation to the pool:

```sh
$ sudo zpool clear content-pool ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZTEP
cannot clear errors for ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZTEP: one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

```sh
$ sudo zpool offline content-pool ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZTEP
cannot open 'content-pool': pool is unavailable
```

```sh
$ sudo zpool scrub content-pool
cannot scrub 'content-pool': pool is currently unavailable
```

Even I tried to replace the dead drive or clear the pool status:

```sh
$ sudo zpool replace content-pool 1078152416620325459 ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D168PDHT
cannot open 'content-pool': pool is unavailable
```

```
$ sudo zpool clear content-pool
cannot clear errors for content-pool: one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Tried to retrieve some details from `sudo zpool events -vf` but no result from above operations

---

**update**: back to the state that pool can't be imported again

current `zpool import`:

(the faulted `ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZTEP` was added by accident before, there is no data in it)

```sh
$ sudo zpool import
   pool: content-pool
     id: 3621552755300412622
  state: UNAVAIL
 status: One or more devices are faulted.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
 config:

    content-pool                             UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      raidz3-0                                    DEGRADED
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D168PVC8  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D363TCL9  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D363TDVX  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D36JR303  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D36JRJD1  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56Z35P  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56Z4JD  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZEX2  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX21D36PPEKZ  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4HV3ZZ  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4LMMMM  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXC1HB4HMLCD  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXN1H84CCEVF  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557Y3SR  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557YAVR  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557YCC2  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PX3KS  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PX3YX  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PXTSC  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11DC4497YV  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX31D2504K74  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX31D65A2C9E  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259T63X  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TE9L  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TJU9  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TVTR  ONLINE
        1078152416620325459                       UNAVAIL
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574KZ5  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574SXZ  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574V07  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX71D65JEZ2C  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX81D6550UR4  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4HSKRY  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX81D65D9LD6  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX91D65DCE04  ONLINE
        ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX91D65DCKR5  ONLINE
      ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZTEP    FAULTED  corrupted data
```

One of the `zdb -l`:

(All the disk in the same pool has almost the same `zdb -l` result, except the `guid:` part is different)

```sh
$ sudo zdb -l /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PX3KS-part1
------------------------------------
LABEL 0
------------------------------------
    version: 5000
    name: 'content-pool'
    state: 0
    txg: 8348544
    pool_guid: 3621552755300412622
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'content-ftp'
    top_guid: 11498459744868090541
    guid: 11818476807007794000
    vdev_children: 2
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'raidz'
        id: 0
        guid: 11498459744868090541
        nparity: 3
        metaslab_array: 166
        metaslab_shift: 40
        ashift: 12
        asize: 216041772810240
        is_log: 0
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 0
            guid: 7798174214455629273
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D168PVC8-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 215
            create_txg: 4
        children[1]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 1
            guid: 9655586118508030176
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D363TCL9-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 214
            create_txg: 4
        children[2]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 2
            guid: 1036444324318734332
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D363TDVX-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 213
            create_txg: 4
        children[3]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 3
            guid: 1671251092857451329
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D36JR303-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 212
            create_txg: 4
        children[4]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 4
            guid: 4180777695415546678
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11D36JRJD1-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 211
            create_txg: 4
        children[5]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 5
            guid: 9587968578374614856
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56Z35P-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 210
            create_txg: 4
        children[6]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 6
            guid: 2726944175730713275
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56Z4JD-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 209
            create_txg: 4
        children[7]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 7
            guid: 15058102474771879213
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX11DB56ZEX2-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 208
            create_txg: 4
        children[8]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 8
            guid: 2176583035980080357
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WX21D36PPEKZ-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 207
            create_txg: 4
        children[9]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 9
            guid: 12213605498789728384
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4HV3ZZ-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 206
            create_txg: 4
        children[10]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 10
            guid: 16692863623985590265
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4LMMMM-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 205
            create_txg: 4
        children[11]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 11
            guid: 4131222994089368621
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXC1HB4HMLCD-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 204
            create_txg: 4
        children[12]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 12
            guid: 10405780603842776111
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXN1H84CCEVF-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 203
            create_txg: 4
        children[13]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 13
            guid: 4802054319391370846
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557Y3SR-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 202
            create_txg: 4
        children[14]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 14
            guid: 14336049427456271508
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557YAVR-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 201
            create_txg: 4
        children[15]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 15
            guid: 5171261257149665977
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D557YCC2-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 200
            create_txg: 4
        children[16]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 16
            guid: 11818476807007794000
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PX3KS-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 199
            create_txg: 4
        children[17]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 17
            guid: 12514554540177747308
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PX3YX-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 198
            create_txg: 4
        children[18]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 18
            guid: 411055325634056854
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11D55PXTSC-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 197
            create_txg: 4
        children[19]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 19
            guid: 9168663998575981435
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX11DC4497YV-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 196
            create_txg: 4
        children[20]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 20
            guid: 4385217325944977250
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX31D2504K74-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 195
            create_txg: 4
        children[21]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 21
            guid: 12169669977314753282
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX31D65A2C9E-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 194
            create_txg: 4
        children[22]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 22
            guid: 2739496474415237206
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259T63X-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 193
            create_txg: 4
        children[23]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 23
            guid: 15921933850909040039
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TE9L-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 192
            create_txg: 4
        children[24]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 24
            guid: 13900183369170026888
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TJU9-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 191
            create_txg: 4
        children[25]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 25
            guid: 10729475082755539900
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX41D259TVTR-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 190
            create_txg: 4
        children[26]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 26
            guid: 1078152416620325459
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574E35-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            not_present: 1
            DTL: 189
            create_txg: 4
        children[27]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 27
            guid: 7169212150010223263
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574KZ5-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 188
            create_txg: 4
        children[28]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 28
            guid: 10688002672848252538
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574SXZ-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 187
            create_txg: 4
        children[29]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 29
            guid: 14475182699961610412
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX61D6574V07-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 186
            create_txg: 4
        children[30]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 30
            guid: 1251108739797802502
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX71D65JEZ2C-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 185
            create_txg: 4
        children[31]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 31
            guid: 16567657162171866083
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX81D6550UR4-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 184
            create_txg: 4
        children[32]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 32
            guid: 11324965671804235780
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68L0BN1_WD-WXB1HB4HSKRY-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 1921
            create_txg: 4
        children[33]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 33
            guid: 5940180339143158814
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX81D65D9LD6-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 183
            create_txg: 4
        children[34]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 34
            guid: 437257513201166423
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX91D65DCE04-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 182
            create_txg: 4
        children[35]:
            type: 'disk'
            id: 35
            guid: 13641210868471885912
            path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD60EFRX-68MYMN1_WD-WX91D65DCKR5-part1'
            whole_disk: 1
            DTL: 178
            create_txg: 4
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
    labels = 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: This is the biggest disadvantage of ZFS - you are completly powerless.

Comment: Forgot to mentioned that I tried `zdb -l` to read vdev labels but all failed. Original post updated with this part.

Comment: @EugenRieck I can't be sure right now, but disk SMART status seem to be okay, and just before the system crash, the raidz data pool works just fine, so I think it's hopefully just configuration level problem.

Comment: Thanks for the head up @DanielB, I tried zdb with disk, not partition, now it works when I try with partition.

Comment: I'm not sure which is the "ID" here? However, the disk id under `/dev/disk/by-id/` are correct, and online the dead drive doesn't exist, all the others are alive, I updated the original post with put some of the zdb output and hope that'll help. thanks!

Comment: Please provide the _entire_ output of `zpool import` as well as `zdb -l`.

Comment: I updated with full `zpool status` in the updated section, should I provide `zdb -l` of all the 36-1 hard drives(1 is broken)? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielB since I found that the `zdb -l ` results are most the same except the `guid:` part, so I pasted one of them in the original post, also with the `zpool import` result, thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the `zpool import` output the error is now obvious. You added *another* vdev (single-disk, serial WX11DB56ZTEP) to your pool. This disk is now missing or its ZFS data corrupted or whatever. Unless you have taken a *zpool checkpoint* you are now out of luck.

Your pool is now *irreversibly damaged* and you have to re-create it from backups.

---

There is a chance you can import the pool in its current state to perform backups. First, change the `zfs_max_missing_tvds` parameter:

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_max_missing_tvds
```

Then, you may be able to import the pool like so:

```
sudo zpool import -o readonly=on content-pool
```

Please note that `-o readonly=on` is required. You may get read errors here and there. You *will* have to re-create the pool.

Comment: `WX11DB56ZTEP` was added by accident, originally I want to use it to replace the unavailable hard drive, it should not contain data on it, is there any chance that I can rollback the zpool status to a state before the drive was added?

Comment: btw, the drive `WX11DB56ZTEP` is still there, and shouldn't be damaged, I guess the reason it's being damage is because I removed it(remove it because it was added by accident), want to use another disk with a difference serial number to replace the unavailable, real damaged one

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but for a raidz3 pool, shouldn't it be recoverable as there is only one real damaged hard drive? I expected it allows 3 damaged disk without losing data on it.

Comment: You don’t have a RAIDZ3 pool. You have a pool with a RAIDZ3 vdev and a single disk vdev. There’s a chance that you could re-import the pool with a missing vdev. However, I cannot test this now. You’ll still have to re-create the pool.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood that before, trying to find out the way to import it with missing vdev now, just want to confirm, the re-create process, does it need me to erase the whole pool so that I can create a new one? Really want to preserve the data on it. If the problem it's because the accident added vdev, that's very interesting ...

Comment: Can I say I have a RAIDZ3 pool if the single disk vdev was not added, only the RAIDZ3 vdev exists?

Comment: That’s misleading terminology. A pool is a pool and a vdev is a vdev. // Yes, you absolutely positively have to re-create everything from scratch.